# Passing elements & performing computations on a list within dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form:-

```
DictName = {'A1': {'B': ['B1', 'B2'], 'C': ['C1', 'C2']}, 'A2': {'B': ['B3', 'B4'], 'C': ['C3', 'C4']}}
```

My attempts at performing calculations on the list elements have been futile

for eg:

```
[B1, B2] - [B3 - B4]
```

I'm using the following code in a function to calculate distance:

```
 def _calculate_distance(x,y):
 return sqrt(sum(pow(a - b,2) for a, b in zip(x, y)))
```

I'm passing two lists (ListA & ListB) to the function of the form:

```
ListA = DictName[A1]
ListB = DictName[A2]
```

I get the following error which points back to the function mentioned above:-

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

I think I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Any suggestions on how to pass the elements of the list (B1,B2,B3,B4) within the dictionary (B) based on the key value (A) which is enclosed in a dictionary of itself, so that computations can be performed?

I hope this makes sense. Would be glad if anyone can help !

Comment: What is the actual code that generates that error?

Comment: @johnchase its the function mentioned above. Thats where the error gets raised

Comment: What are the arguments you are using to call the function?

Comment: The function is not generating the error. The function call which is not shown in your question is generating the error. The function is working how you expect, however the arguments to the function are not valid, without knowing how you are calling the function it will be impossible to say what you are doing wrong. `_calculate_distance([1, 2], [2, 3])` works for me

Comment: @Alec  edited abbove, please take a look

Comment: @johnchase edited above, please take a look

Comment: Sorry for not being precise, pretty new to programming

Answer (score 0):

The function `_calculate_distance` takes two lists.

If your dictionary looks like this:

```
DictName = {'A1': {'B': [1, 2], 'C': [1, 1]}, 'A2': {'B': [1, 4], 'C': [3, 2]}}
```

and you want to pass the list in `'A1', 'B'` you can access that list with the following:

```
DictName['A1']['B']
[1, 2]
```

These lists can then be passed to the distance function

```
_calculate_distance(DictName['A1']['B'], DictName['A1']['C'])
2.2360679774997898
```

Hope this helps